Did Maharaja know that it was not his daughter?
In the movie maharaja did Maharaja know that after the accident it was not his daughter who was alive? Or he mix it up? Asking because in the end when Selvam wanted to ask for forgiveness from her daughter Maharaja says it is not her daughter.

Yes, he always knew that she was not his daughter. His daughter and his wife died during the incident that happened at the beginning of the movie. In that incident, Selvam's daughter and his wife were also present there, but unfortunately his wife died. Laxmi saved his daughter. When Maharaja showed that his wife and his daughter had died and Anurag's daughter was alive, he decided to take care of Anurag's daughter just like his own.
I hope you understand.

If you loved Maharaja  then I would like to recommend one more intense movie named Por thozhil its available on sonyliv.

Yes, he knows that she is not his daughter. But he tells Anurag that's not his daughter(Anurag's) because he loved her and raised her as his own.
